# Snapping and edge loop cut

Tags: snapping

What is best way to snapp vertices when I add edge loop in retopology for instance and they don't snapp.I take every vertex and hit G to snap it.

Comment: Could you be more specific ? Do you have a picture showing what you need ? Or even the blend file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you select several vertices and move them, they should automatically snap if you have these two options enabled: *Align Rotation To Target* and *Project Individual Elements*.

[image]